# How / When / Where should I use the hidden field?

Tags: hidden, hidden-field, hiddenfield

I have a dropdown that contain a list of people which contain also a unique id number like for example `data1` contain `ID = 5`. How the ID of 5 pass to the hidden field?.

I'm having trouble understanding on how / where / when to use the hidden field like this

`<input type="hidden" id="hidPersonId" />`

I'm always asking myself how the hidden field has the value when a scenario is adding a data. How did the hidden field get the value or ID. Please explain to me how did that happen if possible step by step?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidden fields` are made in `.cshtml` view of the page. Like in your example how did the hidden field get the ID of 5?. After the event of change`(choose from the dropdown)` the ID is pass to the hidden field. For example

This event is on change function.

```
var drpSample = $("#drpID").val(); //--- let say the ID is 5

$("#hidPersonId").val(drpSample);
```

Comment: so that's how the hidden field get the id. Thanks for the explanation and simple example. CHeers +1